# PHP XML Decode File

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, decode

how can I get a list with the "steamID64" from that xml file via php?: 
http://steamcommunity.com/groups/BillKeyTrading/memberslistxml/?xml=1

Thats my current code:

```
$file = simplexml_load_file('http://steamcommunity.com/groups/BillKeyTrading/memberslistxml/?xml=1
');

    foreach ($file->members as $steam){
        $steamid64=$steam->steamID64;

        echo $steamid64;

    }
```

Thank you very much.
with best regards
Hamacka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `id`s, not the `member`s. You only have 1 member.

```
foreach ($file->members->steamID64 as $steam){
        echo $steam . "\n";
}
```

Alternatively loop inside your loop for each id:

```
foreach ($file->members as $steam){
        foreach($steam->steamID64 as $steamid64) {
             echo $steamid64 . "\n";
        }
}
```

https://eval.in/699683

Comment: Perfect, ´Thank you very much.